# Cannot finish the airport!

Tags: far-cry-4

I killed everybody in the airport, now the airport is still red and I can not finish the propaganda mission! What do I have to do?

Comment: [Walkthroughs are everywhere these days](https://www.google.com/search?q=far+cry+4+airport&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari) kind of takes the fun out it.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short **You can't yet**

It's actually done during the mission

> Free Willis

A guide to it can be found [here](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/far-cry-4/Free_Willis). Other than that, you cannot liberate it.